# Javascript regex to check for exact alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

These are the special characters, numbers and alphabets that i need to check if user inputs 
if the user does not input as per below criteria throw an alert message .

1. (dash)
2. (underscore)
3. (period)
4. (
5. Space
6. )
7. &
8. $
9. #
10. Numeric
11. Albhapet

For this i have a regex that i came up with,with the help of some articles online

My regex

```
/^\w\s-.()&$#/  

    -- Here, \w matches letter , digits and underscores
    --       \s matches spaces table and line breaks. 
    --       -  matches the hypen in the character set example [a-z]
```

Example-- str is passed as

1. Name123&  ---- true
2. Name 123$ ---- true
3. Name@@@   ---- False since @ is not permissiable
4. Name-._&  ---- True
5. Name@._&$ ---  False since @ is not permissiable
6. Name.[]   ---  False since [] is not permissiable

```
function checkfirmName(str) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^\w\s-.()&$#/); //acceptable char

    if (pattern.test(str)) {
        return true; //good user input
    }

    alert("Please only use \nUnderScore,Dot,(,Space,),&,$,# \nThese are only allowed\n");

    return false;  // bad user input 
}
```

I am also not sure if the test extension works (it return true- false ) but not sure if it iterates through and checks every character, so i found another piece of code using indexof:

```
function isValid(str) {
    var iChars = "/^\w\s-.()&$#/";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (iChars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            $.alert("File name has should have special characters \nUnderScore,Dot,(,Space,),&,$,# \nThese are only allowed\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a character class that contains all allowed character sets:

```
/^[-\w .()&$#]+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2UoD3y/1)

- You need to use anchors in your regex.
- An unescaped hyphen should be at first or last position in a character class.

---

An alternative approach is to look for any not allowed character and fail the match if that is found:

```
function checkfirmName(str) {
    const pattern = /[^-\w .()&$#]/; //not-acceptable char

    if (pattern.test(str)) {
        alert("Please only use \nUnderScore,Dot,(,Space,),&,$,# \nThese are only allowed\n");
        return false; // bad user input
    }

    return true;  // good user input 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) very helpful in explaining and testing regular expressions for Python and Javascript. As per your requirment, I believe the following will be useful, `^[-\.\(\) \&$\#\w]+$`

\w: Because it takes care of all numbers, alphabets and underscore.

With respect to JS, the code could be like

```
function isValid(str) {
    var patt = /^[-\.\(\) \&$\#\w]+$/;
    return patt.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Put the ^ inside the set. This will behave as a negated set.
Regex should be `/[^-.(\s)&$#\w]/`

Comment: I added caret to check as the start of the string and dollar at the end to check as the end of the string.